# Stripping a string in a list in Python

Tags: python, string

I got a problem inserting an element into a loop...

```
import bs4

# Acces and read HTML file
exempleFile = open('betradar21.html', encoding="utf8")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exempleFile.read(), features="html.parser")

s = ["'tr', {'id': 'match-23206483'}", "'tr', {'id': 'match-23362461'}", "'tr', {'id': 'match- 
24358676'}", "'tr', {'id': 'match-21571325'}", "'tr', {'id': 'match-24325629'}", "'tr', {'id': 
'match-24352074'}", "'tr', {'id': 'match-24352106'}", "'tr', {'id': 'match-24352108'}", "'tr', {'id': 
'match-24352110'}", "'tr', {'id': 'match-24352112'}", "'tr', {'id': 'match-24423426'}", "'tr', {'id': 
'match-24423436'}"]


def dequote(s):
    '''
    If a string has single or double quotes around it, remove them.
    Make sure the pair of quotes match.
    If a matching pair of quotes is not found, return the string unchanged.
    '''
    if (s[0] == s[-1]) and s.startswith(("'", '"')):
        return s[1:-1]
    return s



for i, v in enumerate(s):
    dequote(v)
    print(v)
    print(soup.find_all(v))
    break
```

This will return an empty list just as v is a string surrounded by "".

```
print(soup.find_all("'tr', {'id': 'match-23206483'}"))
```

If i take manually with copy and paste the value of v after I strip it from double quotes works just fine...

```
print(soup.find_all('tr', {'id': 'match-23206483'}))
```

Like this...

Why does Python does this and there is a way that I can "fix" this? I guess it has something to do with {} but as a rookie in programming I couldn't find the explanation yet!

Thanks

Comment: `dequote` function returns modified string, but you don't use them. Just calling `dequote` doing nothing.

Comment: And you should use evaluation functions to replace expression by string. In your case, v is just string not expression.

Comment: I think you need to use regular expressions here as single quote or double quote are both in built identifiers for in-built class `__str__` Whenever we parse Double quote `print("Hello")` or do it with single quote `print('Hello')` the in-built class is responsible for both the matches. You are using string function `.startswith()` which is nothing but a identifier for both objects (Single and double quotes)

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna learn how to do that. Thanks

Comment: I can't run your code because the lines initializing `s` terminate mid-string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets focus on a smaller test set

```
s = ["'tr', {'id': 'match-23206483'}"]
```

Those double quotes you see aren't part of the string, they are just the delimiters used in python string literals to tell the parser that it is supposed to build a string from the content. Internally, that string is

```
'tr', {'id': 'match-23206483'}
```

it starts with a `'` and ends with a `}`. `dequote` doesn't do anything because `s[0]` (`'`) does not equal `s[-1]` (`}`). So we can take `dequote` out of the equation and get to the rest of the code.

```
for i, v in enumerate(s):
    print(v)
    print(soup.find_all(v))
    break
```

`v` is a single string. It looks kind of like a parameter list, but its really just a single string. It needs to be parsed somehow if its going to become the parameters you want for `soup.find_all`. In fact, `v` looks an awful lot like a python literal for a tuple. You can have python evaluate the string and build the tuple for you.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("'tr', {'id': 'match-23206483'}")
('tr', {'id': 'match-23206483'})
```

Good. We can turn the data into a tuple and with tuple unpacking we get the parameter list for `find_all`.

```
import ast

for i, v in enumerate(s):
    print(v)
    params = ast.literal_eval(v)
    print(soup.find_all(*params))
    break
```

Comment: Thank you , muchos gracias senior :)